# Java simple PizzaOrder

Tags: java

I am stuck and have an error here.
I am making a simple pizza ordering program. The program is just about inputting the pizza size and toppings, then it will show the price and everything. 
What I want to do is, when I press enter in the topping selection without inputting anything, it should return a zero. Here is the code

```
    <pre>
      public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter The Size of Pizza you " + "want: (S/M/L/C)");
    String option = keyboard.nextLine().trim()
    .toUpperCase();

    if(!option.isEmpty())
        option = option.substring(0, 1);


    double pizzaPrice;
    double pizzaSize;


    if(option.equals(PIZZA_MEDIUM))
    {
        pizzaPrice = PRICE_MEDIUM;
        pizzaSize = MEDIUM_DIAMETER;
    }
    else if (option.equals(PIZZA_LARGE))
    {
        pizzaPrice = PRICE_LARGE;
        pizzaSize = LARGE_DIAMETER;
    }
    else if (option.equals(PIZZA_COLOSSAL))
    {
        pizzaPrice = PRICE_COLOSSAL;
        pizzaSize = COLOSSAL_DIAMETER;
    }
    else
    {
        option = PIZZA_SMALL;           
        pizzaPrice = PRICE_SMALL;
        pizzaSize = SMALL_DIAMETER;
    }


    System.out.println("Pizza Size: " + option);
    System.out.println("Enter The Number of Toppings" +
    "you want:(0-8)");
    int pizzaTopping=0;


    if(keyboard.hasNextInt())
        pizzaTopping = keyboard.nextInt();      


    if(pizzaTopping < MIN_TOPPINGS)
    {
        pizzaTopping = MIN_TOPPINGS;
    }
    else if(pizzaTopping > MAX_TOPPINGS)
    {
        pizzaTopping = MAX_TOPPINGS;
    }
    else    
    {
        pizzaTopping = pizzaTopping;
    }
```

I have done it with the string for the pizza size with using

```
   if(!option.isEmpty())
```

I think its not working on an integer. What should I do?

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to happen if you enter nothing when prompted for toppings? Currently pizzaTopping should stay `0`.

Comment: If I enter nothing, I want the toppings to be zero. 
but it just makes space, like an enter should be.. its not crash but its just empty; the enter just making blank space (I use cmd as an output)

Comment: What error are you getting?  As the answer below indicates your pizzaTopping variable should stay 0.  Do you just want to print the results and then return?

Comment: its not like an error actually. When I put in enter without inputting anything, the program is just makes spacing instead of running. what I want is, when I press enter without inputting any number, the output become zero.(sorry for bad english, its not my first language) this is my first program after hello world

Comment: Please paste rest of the code. Since pizzaTopping is an `int`, it shouldn't come as blank space but `0`. There seems to be some other problem. Show the code where you're using its value.

Comment: I see, the answer given by duck42 is a good one in this case then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code to set it to zero(0) if there is no value (or any other invalid value):

```
String toppingsString = keyboard.nextLine().trim();
int toppings = 0;
try
{
     toppings = Integer.parseInt(toppingsString);
}
catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
{
    toppings = 0;
}
```

Comment: but my pizzatopping is an integer, because it stand for the topping(0-8). should i change it into string?

Comment: Essentially what this code does is first it gets the value as a String. Next, it tries to convert it to an int, but if there is an error (a NumberFormatException, which occurs when if the person inputted a non-integer value like 'a', 'b', '!', or, in your case, empty space), it will set it to the default value of 0. So, finally, you get the # of toppings you need inside the variable toppings, but you are going to want to add your code that makes sure that the value is not above the maximum and not below the minimum.

Comment: Make sure you remove the lines: `if(keyboard.hasNextInt())`
        `pizzaTopping = keyboard.nextInt();`

Answer (score 0):

Add an `else` like

```
if(!option.isEmpty())
    option = option.substring(0, 1); // <-- Could also use Character.toString()
else
    option = "0";
```

Or, a [conditional operation `? :`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) (aka ternary) and [`Character.toString(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toString%28char%29) and something like

```
option = (option.isEmpty()) ? "0" : Character.toString(option.charAt(0));
```

And for the `toppings`, I'd use `Math.max()` and `Math.min()` like

```
int pizzaTopping = MIN_TOPPINGS;
if(keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
    pizzaTopping = keyboard.nextInt();      
}
pizzaTopping = Math.max(Math.min(pizzaTopping, MAX_TOPPINGS), MIN_TOPPINGS);
```

Comment: actually, I the problem is at the topping part. the size part is alright.

Comment: Thanks for the help on that part tho

Comment: the problem is like.. when I run the program, it will tell
enter the size of pizza....
<Enter without inputting anything>
"and the pizza will become small size"
Enter the number of topping you want:
<Enter without inputting anything>
"it just making blank space everytime I press enter, instead of 0(as the minimum topping)"
<blank>
<blank>
<blank>

Comment: it will just making blank space until i put some number or letter on it